# Issue with division of a 0 / input validation

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I'm getting an exception at line 223: `//calculation for vat ( room cost take 25% )`

> System.DivideByZeroException: 'Attempted to divide by zero.'

the fixes i have tried have been to add in if else statements from lines 224 to 230 to allow the sum to retry so that it just puts a number without the crash but this has not helped. any possible fix ?

```
public partial class paint : Form
{
    private int price, price21;

    public paint()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Button for Calculations 
    private void SUB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validation() == 0)
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Totals Below");
        }

        // northwall calculations and inputs to variables
        if (txtnorthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtnorthheight.Text = ("0");
        }

        if (txtnorthlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtnorthlength.Text = ("0");
        }

        decimal height1 = decimal.Parse(txtnorthheight.Text);
        decimal length1 = decimal.Parse(txtnorthlength.Text);
        decimal area1 = height1 * length1;
        lblnortharea.Text = area1.ToString("n");

        // southwall calculations and inputs to variables
        if (txtsouthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtsouthheight.Text = ("0");
        }

        if (txtsouthlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtsouthlength.Text = ("0");
        }

        decimal height2 = decimal.Parse(txtsouthheight.Text);
        decimal length2 = decimal.Parse(txtsouthlength.Text);
        decimal area2 = height2 * length2;
        lblsoutharea.Text = area2.ToString("n");

        // Eastwall calculations and inputs to variables
        if (txteasthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txteasthheight.Text = ("0");
        }

        if (txteasthlength.Text == "")
        {
            txteasthlength.Text = ("0");
        }

        decimal height3 = decimal.Parse(txteasthheight.Text);
        decimal length3 = decimal.Parse(txteasthlength.Text);
        decimal area3 = height3 * length3;
        lbleastarea.Text = area3.ToString("n");

        // Westhwall calculations and inputs to variables
        if (txtwesthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtwesthheight.Text = ("0");
        }

        if (txtwestlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtwestlength.Text = ("0");
        }

        decimal height4 = decimal.Parse(txtwesthheight.Text);
        decimal length4 = decimal.Parse(txtwestlength.Text);
        decimal area4 = height4 * length4;
        lblwestharea.Text = area4.ToString("n");

        // window frame calculations and inputs to variables
        if (txtwinheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtwinheight.Text = ("0");
        }

        if (txtwinlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtwinlength.Text = ("0");
        }

        decimal height5 = decimal.Parse(txtwinheight.Text);
        decimal length5 = decimal.Parse(txtwinlength.Text);
        decimal area5 = height5 * length5;
        lblwinharea.Text = area5.ToString("n");

        // culculation to work out total area - window size. this is borken in to two aprts:
        // area 1 + area 2 + area 3 + area 5 then take away area 5 which is the window. 
        decimal areatotal = (area1 + area2 + area3 + area4) - area5;

        lbltotalarea.Text = areatotal.ToString("n");

        // culculations for total height and length for output in invoice. 
        decimal Heightt = (height1 + height2 + height3 + height4) - height5;
        decimal Legntht = (length1 + length2 + length3 + length4) - length5;
        Height2.Text = Heightt.ToString("n");
        Legnth.Text = Legntht.ToString("n");

        // variables for inputs taken on qucilty options and undercoat option.
        if (txtunder.Text == "")
        {
            txtunder.Text = ("0");
        }
        if (txtprice.Text == "")
        {
            txtprice.Text = ("0");
        }

        decimal price = decimal.Parse(txtprice.Text);
        decimal undercoat = decimal.Parse(txtunder.Text);
        decimal roomcost = (Heightt * Legntht) * price * undercoat;
        lblcost.Text = roomcost.ToString("c");

        //culculation for vat ( room cost take 25% ) 
        decimal Vattotal = (25 % roomcost);
        lblvat.Text = Vattotal.ToString("c");

         //culculation for roomcost + vat
         Decimal vt = Vattotal + roomcost;
         lblbt.Text = vt.ToString("c");           
    }

    // reset form button
    private void Totalcost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtwinlength.Text = "";
        txtnorthheight.Text = "";
        txtnorthlength.Text = "";
        txtwesthheight.Text = "";
        txtwestlength.Text = "";
        txtsouthheight.Text = "";
        txtsouthlength.Text = "";
        txteasthheight.Text = "";
        txteasthlength.Text = "";
        txtwinheight.Text = "";
        txtprice.Text = "";
        lblnortharea.Text = "";
        lblsoutharea.Text = "";
        lblwestharea.Text = "";
        lbleastarea.Text = "";
        lblwinharea.Text = "";
        lblcost.Text = "";
        lbltotalarea.Text = "";
        Height2.Text = "";
        Legnth.Text = "";
        invoice.Text = "";
    }

    // invoice number genrator 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slumpGenerator = new Random(); int tal;
        tal = slumpGenerator.Next();
        invoice.Text = tal.ToString("n");
    }

    // invoice OUTput
    private void label22_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slumpGenerator = new Random(); int tal;
        tal = slumpGenerator.Next();
        invoice.Text = tal.ToString("n");
    }

    //input vaildation only allowing numbers and decimals. 
    private void txtnorthheight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtnorthlength_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtsouthheight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtsouthlength_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtprice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtwesthheight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtwestlength_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txteasthheight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txteasthlength_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtwinheight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtwinlength_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    private void txtunder_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Value");
        }
    }

    public int validation ()
    {
        int flag = 0;

        //North input valdation
        if (txtnorthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtnorthheight.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtnorthheight, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (txtnorthlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtnorthlength.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtnorthlength, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        //South input valdation
        if (txtsouthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtsouthheight.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtsouthheight, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (txtsouthlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtsouthlength.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtsouthlength, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        //West  input valdation
        if (txtwesthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtwesthheight.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtwesthheight, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (txtwestlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtwestlength.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtwestlength, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        //East input valdation
        if (txteasthheight.Text == "")
        {
            txteasthheight.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txteasthheight, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (txteasthlength.Text == "")
        {
            txteasthlength.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txteasthlength, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        //Window input valdation
        if (txtwinheight.Text == "")
        {
            txtwinheight.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtwinheight, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (txtwinlength.Text == "")
        {
            txtwinlength.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtwinlength, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input between 0.9m and 1.5m.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        //quality input valdation
        if (txtprice.Text == "")
        {
            txtprice.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtprice, MessageBox.Show("please Enter a vaild input of the above options ( You Must Enter 1 of the Options).", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }

        // undercoat valdation
        if (txtunder.Text == "")
        {
            txtunder.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtunder, MessageBox.Show("Please enter the Undercoat input of 0.45, if you do not want undercoat enter 0.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }
        return flag;
    }

    private void txtnorthheight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }
    //end of valdation
}
```

Comment: Show us only the important part of code.

Comment: Why are you using mod to calculate percentage? To get 25% of room cost, multiply by 0.25 or divide by 4.

Comment: `(25 % roomcost)` is not 25% of the room cost, it's [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).  `roomcost` must be zero, which is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` symbol is the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) in `C#`, which means it gives you the remainder after dividing the left side by the right side. In your code, it looks like you want to get 25% of the room cost, not the remainder of 25 divided by the room cost.

So, this line:

```
decimal Vattotal = (25 % roomcost);
```

Should be changed to:

```
decimal Vattotal = roomcost * .25;
```

The reason you're getting the exception is that `roomcost` is `0`, and dividing by zero is an illegal operation.